# Parsing inconsistent data with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, text-parsing

I need to write SQL to extract repeat location codes and separate out the sub-location detail. However, the data I am working with does not follow a set pattern.

Here's a sample of what the location codes look like (the real table has over 5,000 locations):

`JR-DY-TIN
 DY-RHOLD
 DY-PREQ-TIN
 GLVCSH
 GLFLR
 GLBOX1
 GLBOX2
 GLBOX3
 GLBOXA
 GLBOXB
 GLBOXC
 GLBOXD
 GL
 GL0001
 GL0002
 GL0003
 GL0014
 …`

I was able to create a new column for the sub-location detail when it is numeric but that's all I have so far.

```
select 
  LocationCode,
  REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(LocationCode),PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z]%',  
  REVERSE(LocationCode))-1)) AS PaddedNumbers
from LocationTable 


Results...

LocationCode     PaddedNumbers     
------------     -------------     
JR-DY-TIN                          
DY-RHOLD                           
DY-PREQ-TIN                        
GLVCSH                             
GLFLR                              
GLBOX1           1                 
GLBOX2           2  
GLBOX3           3  
GLBOXA      
GLBOXB      
GLBOXC      
GLBOXD      
GL      
GL0001           0001   
GL0002           0002   
GL0003           0003   
GL0014           0014
```

I still figure out how to display the following in two separate columns:

- Location codes without the sub-locations detail, e.g. GLBOX , or just
  the original location code if there is no sub-location, e.g. GLFLR.
- Numeric and Nonnumeric sub-location detail at the same time, e.g. for
  GLBOX have a column that displays 1, 2, 3,A, B, C, D, E, F.

Edit: If I am able to accomplish this the data should look like this:

```
LocationCode     MainLoc        SubLoc
------------     ---------      ------
JR-DY-TIN        JR-DY-TIN                         
DY-RHOLD         DY-RHOLD                  
DY-PREQ-TIN      DY-PREQ-TIN                  
GLVCSH           GLVCSH                  
GLFLR            GLFLR                 
GLBOX1           GLBOX          1               
GLBOX2           GLBOX          2
GLBOX3           GLBOX          3
GLBOXA           GLBOX          A
GLBOXB           GLBOX          B
GLBOXC           GLBOX          C
GLBOXD           GLBOX          D
GL               GL
GL0001           GL             0001    
GL0002           GL             0002    
GL0003           GL             0003    
GL0014           GL             0014
```

Any help is appreciated.

Environment: SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Can you show what you would like the final result to look like?

Comment: Do you have a list of all the valid location codes?

Comment: Yes, the list is over 5,000 locations.

Comment: @Jeff.Clark: I updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @LocationRef TABLE (Location NVARCHAR(20), Ref INT)

INSERT INTO @LocationRef VALUES
     ('JR-DY-TIN',0)
    ,('DY-RHOLD',0)
    ,('DY-PREQ-TIN',0)
    ,('GLVCSH',0)
    ,('GLFLR',0)
    ,('GLBOX1',6)
    ,('GLBOX2',6)
    ,('GLBOX3',6)
    ,('GLBOXA',6)
    ,('GLBOXB',6)
    ,('GLBOXC',6)
    ,('GLBOXD',6)
    ,('GL',0)
    ,('GL0001',3)
    ,('GL0002',3)
    ,('GL0003',3)
    ,('GL0014',3)

SELECT   Location AS LocationCode
    ,LEFT(Location,CASE Ref WHEN 0 THEN LEN(Location) ELSE Ref - 1  END)
    ,RIGHT(Location,CASE Ref WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE LEN(Location) - Ref + 1 END)
FROM @LocationRef
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to use something like a `parseInt` feature, which is not available in `SQL Server 2008`. You can attempt to use `cast`, but that won't work with your datatype - `varchar`.

I'd suggest using a case statement to parse the complex logic you need. ie:

```
select 
  LocationCode,
  case when left(LocationCode,5) like 'GLBOX%' then substring(LocationCode,5,2) 
       when left(LocationCode,3) like 'GL0%' then substring(LocationCode,3,4)
       else 'null' end as ParsedLocationCode end
from LocationTable
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I would use case statements but I'm working with over 5,000 location codes that all vary. To have to hard code that would be inefficient.

Comment: I see. Another approach might be to use another script that has a `parseInt` feature to grab the integers you need, and then create a temp table with the values it maps to. That likely isn't ideal, but it's a way to brute force your mapping as a start.

Comment: @NWest: I need to stick with SQL. This is for a SSRS report. I know I can write custom code in those reports but there has to be a way to do this in SQL.

Comment: Can you build a table of all the locations, with an integer marking where the subpart starts? E.g., 'GL',0 (no subpart); 'GLBOX1',6; 'GL0001',3; etc.? I don't know how else you could distinguish between GLFLR and GLBOXA -- how do you know one is a master location and the other is a sublocation? You can't do it by numbers since you use letters. You can't do it by the fact that it starts with GL and has more characters. The other option is to try to build a table of all the master locations--that should be shorter--and if it doesn't match that list, try to parse out the remaining ones.

Comment: Try this, it should parse your integers: `DECLARE @KeepValues VARCHAR(50),@Str VARCHAR(500) = 'hello123'
SET @KeepValues = '%[^0-9]%' 
WHILE PATINDEX(@KeepValues, @Str) > 0
SET @Str = STUFF(@Str, PATINDEX(@KeepValues, @Str), 1,'')
select @Str`

Comment: @DaveX: The locations are stored in a table but there is no indicator, other than visually seeing that some locations have sublocations because some of the first couple of characters repeat, like GLBOX. Maybe I can write a query to keep the first 3 characters of the locationcode field then do a group by to identify the master locations??? Then from there write a case statement, if locationcode is a master location (don't know how I'll do this part yet) & last character is numeric then use this parsing syntax, or if it ends in a varchar use this parsing syntax....I'll play with it.

Comment: @LeSteelBox . . . You should ask another question with more detail about your actual problem.  I think John has answered the question you did ask.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I already wrote something for extracting sublocation detail when it was an integer and put it in my initial post, i.e., "REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(LocationCode),PatIndex(..." John Skilbeck just wrote a more elegant version, which I will use...Thanks John.

Comment: @LeSteelBox, I still see potential problems because it doesn't seem like there are enough rules that were used when creating the location names. Even my idea about the master locations has problems, because you could have XY, XY1, XYZ and XYZ1; how does it know if XYZ1 is a sub of XY or XYZ? Short of modifying all the location names, which probably isn't a possibility, I would either just build in another column in the table of locations, or make another table that cross-links the character location. I'm sure you can see what I'm saying, but I'll build a quick query and put it below.

Comment: @DaveX: Yes, I don't know why these location codes were created this way but nothing I can do about that now. I wish I could use the solutions below but there are thousands of location codes and I can't go in and write case statements for all of the ones that have a sublocation.

Comment: @LeSteelBox, I feel your pain. I don't know how to logically parse out values from a system that was set up without logic in the first place. One approach, even though there are thousands of lines, is to dump the existing table to Excel and write some basic rules (like the numeric one) and then go fill in the gaps for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

John's answer seems basically correct.  I would write it as:

```
select LocationCode,
       (case when LocationCode like 'GLBOX%' then right(LocationCode, 1) 
             when LocationCode like 'GL%' then right(LocationCode, 4)
        end) as ParsedLocationCode
from LocationTable
```

This changes:

- Removes the unnecessary `substring()` before `like`.
- Fixed a syntax error (probably a typo with an extra `end`).
- Uses `right()`, just because it seems simpler.

Comment: Thank you but this would only work if I had a small list of locations to go through. I have over 5,000 so hard coding in what the master location should be like isn't really an option or solution for my problem.